# Is there anyway to make Ubuntu 22.04 remember the size and location of windows?

Tags: 22.04, window, settings

In older versions of Ubuntu when I open a window (*example.png*) and change the size and location, when you open it again Ubuntu remembers it, but now with Ubuntu 22.04 it just opens in top left corner and it's just frustrating since i makes the whole experience inconvenient and unproductive.

**Is there anyway to achieve that?**

Comment: Which DE are you using? GNOME?

Comment: You can use the command line tool `wmctrl` to set window sizes and move windows to where you want them. Put the commands into a shellscript to make it easy to get what you want.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer**: No.

**Longer answer**: Window size is hinted by the application, window position is determined by the application, and if it does not, then the window manager will decide on the position. Ubuntu Desktop based on Gnome Shell uses a "smart" algorithm, where a window is placed either on a free space on the desktop, or, slightly lower and to the right, above another window. It can, however, be set to place each new window in the center of the screen. The setting is available in Gnome Tweaks, "Windows" tab.

The behavior depends per application. Evince Document reader, for example, will remember window size and position for each individual file (at least for a certain period), and restore the window when the file is opened. Files will remember the size of the most recently closed window, and adopt that size for a new window. Other applications will open as they were last close, or will just open with a same default size.

If you would switch from Wayland to Xorg, then you still could use one of the venerable tools `devilspie` or `devilspie2`, utilities that provide a way to define where and how a new window meeting specific conditions should be positioned and sized.

Comment: Is it true that the situation worsened, as the OP suggests? I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10, and at least this is as well my personal feeling...