# Remember the window positions of closed apps in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, evince

In ubuntu 22.04, I want the applications to open in the same position where I closed them. It doesn't remember the window positions.

I need it mainly for the system apps: Nautilus, Evince, Settings, Terminal, etc. It's better if there's an option where I'll be able to toggle this according to my preference. The most I can do is open the applications in the middle of the screen (there's an option in gnome-tweaks) but it doesn't help for me.

In case of evince, the app doesn't remember where I left off too, the pdf opens again on the first page, and I have to scroll all the way up to the page where I left off again. Is there an option to change this too?

Comment: `evince, the app doesn't remember where I left off too, the pdf opens again on the first page` -- Use Okular instead. `sudo apt install okular`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to make ubutnu 22.04 remember the size and location of windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410229/is-there-anyway-to-make-ubutnu-22-04-remember-the-size-and-location-of-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You are tacking a difficult issue on the Linux desktop (and perhaps other desktops as well). There is little user control on window placement, and the behavior between different applications may be different:

- Many applications remember their window size
- Other applications open with a specific default size
- The window position is usually decided by the window manager.

In the case of Ubuntu desktop (Gnome Shell), there is the "smart" option and the "always center" option that you also discovered, but this is how far control on window positioning goes.

The only way to have full automatic control on window placement is to use a tool like `devilspie` or `devilspie2`. These tools are old, unmaintained but work fine on systems running Xorg. You define rules on how windows meeting certain criteria should be sized and placed on the desktop. Unfortunately, they do not work on Wayland, the new system that now in Ubuntu 22.04 is used by default. Xorg, however, remains available.

I am sorry not being able to give a more satisfactory answer. I also hope, along with you that a better answer comes along, so I can delete this answer. However, until that moment, this is the state to my knowledge.

With respect to Evince not remembering the last position in the PDF, this is a [regression in the recent version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896).

Answer (score 0):

Xfce remembers window positioning data by default and it's pretty responsive too. I believe KDE does as well. KDE *may* have to be turned on.